# Why isElementPresent does not work?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

There are simple code which wait for dropdown list is displayed on page:

```
var By = this.webdriver.By;
var driver = this.driver;
var bySelector = By.xpath('//*[@id="searchForm"]//*[@class="autocomplete-suggestions autocomplete-suggestion-withgroup"]');
return driver.wait(() => {
    driver.isElementPresent(bySelector);
    }, 6000)
    .then((bool) => {
        assert.isTrue(bool);
    });
```

This code give me an error message: `Error: Wait timed out after 6011ms`

There are an element properties:
[image: here]

After ckicking on search field style property `display:` of this element change on `none` to `block`. 
I can't see also nothing in parent elements, what does this element invisible. I dont understand actually what I does wrong.

I need to click on item in this dropdown list, and now I can do it only after `this.driver.sleep(some ms)`. But it bad practice and I want understand what I does wrong in case use `wait` method and still use it. TY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, а colleague helped me to find a solution to this problem.
Here it is:

```
return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(bySelector), 500, 'not found').then((element) => {
    return driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(element), 5000, 'not found');
});
```

In fact, I did not understand why in some cases sufficient isElementPresent, but in this case it is necessary to write the expression of the two expectations. I will appreciate if someone can explain it to me .

Answer (score 0):

I think the xpath you are using is wrong. try the below xapth.

```
var bySelector = By.xpath('//*[@id="searchForm"]/descendant::*[@class="autocomplete-suggestions autocomplete-suggestion-withgroup"]');
```

Comment: TY, but why do you think that it wrong xpath?
Your code give me the same error.....
Actually I try use many variation xpath expression, but the same error.

Comment: @Valentina you can't write // in the middle of xpath. Use xpath axis for exploring child/descendant elements

Comment: Alexey, why do you think so? Actually, I can use this syntaxis. It is valid xpath expression.